# What does "America" mean?

Tags: meaning

Citizens of the USA naturally refer to themselves as Americans and refer to the country as America.

When speaking to a person from Canada, he argued that it was incorrect to call the country America. Instead, I should be saying the United States (of America).

Is it incorrect to refer to the country as America? And even if it is, won't people from around the world understand that the USA = America?

Comment: @user867 The questions are related, but different IMO. He wants to disambiguate the nationality. I am asking if America is understood as a country name on a global scale.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_(word)) notes that some people, in particular people from Latin America, disagree with the usage of "American" to refer only to _Estadounidenses_ ("United-Statesians") rather than all _Americanos_. Not sure if this applies to the "America" vs "United States of America" distinction as well.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. In that case, be aware that this site's field is the english language, so whatever answers you get will likely refer primarily to areas where it is commonly spoken, and might not hold in other places. Which, of course, might be exactly what you want.

Comment: This is true.  Spanish speakers have tried to introduce the term Estadounidenses into parlance, but as it doesn't trip off the tongue easily, it likely will never have the popularity of Americano.

Comment: Don't you say in French, "je suis un American?" And in German, "ich bin ein Amerikaner?" I think this is common usage to refer to the people of the United States as Americans. Its not just us who call ourselves American. Everyone calls us American. Also, what would you call them if not Americans?

Comment: Hi, I am from Bolivia (South America); in Spanish, what people from USA call "The Americas" is simply called América: A big continent containing three regions: North America, Central America and South America (it actually makes a lot of sense). Thus, for us, calling "American" to people from USA is not correct because we are (giving the explanation above) as American as they are.

Comment: I believe "je suis américain(e)", ie "I am American" is more common.

Comment: Marcel, Canadians still call us Americans, not United-Statesians.

Comment: @MarcelTuring: it may be less common in Canada (I have no statistics to tell one way or the other), but speaking as a W.Canadian, it is certainly very common in Canada to refer to the USA as "America", e.g. when talking about world events; and a citizen of the US is almost always 'American'. Having said that, when I'm in Canada and talk about going to the USA, I'm going "to the 'States". But where does your comment about resentment come from? I think it is more likely to stem from individual hypercorrective tendencies: cultural resentment would suggest shorter, more dismissive names.

Comment: @oopscene: Putting aside the country-vs-continent thing for a second, one can't seriously argue that "America" is one continent without also lumping Europe, Asia, and Africa together as one.  The strip of land connecting the Americas is so skinny, we dug a waterway across it. So now, with the Panama Canal, there's even water between them.  :)  Europe, Asia and Africa can't even say that much.

Comment: As a European, I have no problems identifying "America" with "The USA". If I wanted to talk about any of the two continents, I'd say "North America" or "South America" respectively.

Comment: @cHao Just to nitpick, Africa _does_ have its own analog to the Panama Canal, in the Suez Canal, and so is its own continent according to this specific definition. :)

Comment: @cHaO: Take a look at this: http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/América . It says: America is the second biggest continent after Asia; and that is how I (and all South America people) understand it.

Comment: Mr Lister, I agree. Here in the UK, people regularly refer to the USA as just *America*. There is no ambiguity or issue about it.

Comment: Sudan has the same problem. "Sudan" ("of the blacks") is the region just south of the Sahara. It is also the common name of one of the countries located in that region. Morocco technically has the same problem, being named after the Arabic name for the region west of Egypt while itself only covering a small part of that region. And the "Kingdom of the Netherlands", located in the lowlands (or netherlands) is now known as just the "Netherlands", with the other countries in that region (Belgium and at least two of the German states) being fine with it.

Comment: I think there are two separate issues here. The existing answers cover the geographical part pretty well. But if the demonym of Germany is "German", what is the demonym of the United States? The correct answer is "American". Wikipedia has [a whole article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_for_United_States_citizens) on the subject and cites the OED on this.

Comment: @nitro2k01: Ok, so Africa gets to be separate (and Egypt gets to be part of two continents too).  :)  Eurasia, though, is indisputably one landmass.

Comment: @oopscene  Nobody in the United States minds if Bolivians consider themselves "Americans".  Have at it.

Comment: @JFA while that is true of French (can't speak for German) it is certainly not true in Spanish where most, if not all, South Americans take umbrage at the term. Instead, they say _estadounidense_ which means "_unitedstatesian_". In other words, the people who refer to the US as "America" tend to be those that have no personal stake in the matter.

Comment: @terdon "American" is the only correct demonym for the United States in the English language. "estadounidense" may certainly be correct in Spanish though.

Comment: @terdon I see your point, but I don't think *only* those who have no personal stake in the matter call people of the United States, Americans

Comment: Do people from Germany (for example) call themselves "Europeans" expecting everyone to know that they are the only ones to use the word in that way and that it clearly and unambiguously refers only to people within their country? No. So, "American" meaning USA person is wrong no matter how many people say it or why. I am a life-long USA person, and I still think it is wrong, if not actually arrogant. If it was historical usage, it is time to correct it now. That said, whoever builds the internet first gets to make the rules. That is why ".com", for example, was reserved for within the USA, and

Comment: There is no country called "Germany". There is also no "Russia", no "France", no "China". "Canada" is an absolute exception, not the rule. "America" is the absolute rule, not an exception. Of course I would really like to be around when @krikara informs that Canadian thusly.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I'm not sure if I fully understand what you mean.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Can you explain please? No matter how I look at it, your comment doesn't hold.

Comment: @MrLister I will gladly stop referring to the United States of America as "America" the very minute the Canadian in question stops referring to the Federal Republic of Germany as "Germany", or the People's Republic of China as "China". These are *all* shorthands, the Canadian hasn't thought it through. In other news, no word is limited to a single meaning, and meanings cannot be "correct" or "incorrect". If everyone uses "America" to mean "orange car", then it actually does mean precisely that. That's because no word in an of itself has any meaning *at all* other than the one(s) we give it.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: Ironically enough, as i understand the policy between the PRC and Taiwan, there is one land called "China", and the PRC is one of two governments claiming sovereignty within it.  So the PRC isn't even the only country in China, and the syntactic situation ends up rather similar to that of the USA in the Americas (aside from the desire for China to eventually be one country).

Answer (score 15):

I am a native citizen of the USA.

> Is it incorrect to refer to the country as America?

It depends on context. Within the USA, it is generally understood that "America" refers to the USA (whereas "the Americas", for example, refers to the combined continents of North and South America). Note: This isn't really because of "narrow-mindedness" or anything like that, it's simply because, over time, it has become a norm in AE to use it as shorthand.

Outside of the USA, it depends on both where you are and the context of the conversation. For example, the use of "America" in other countries in the Americas may be offensive to some, or at least ambiguous. Outside of the Americas, probably not offensive (unless you are in a country closely tied to a country in the Americas), but certainly with the rare possibility of ambiguity.

> And even if it is, won't people from around the world understand that the USA = America?

As mentioned above, it really depends. There is no global rule, and the interpretation will depend on where you are, what the common usage of "America" is in the country you are in, and the personal beliefs of whoever you are talking to.

If you are concerned or unsure, simply say "United States". While that is also technically ambiguous (there are other states that are united, actually the official name for Mexico translates to the "United Mexican States"; but for whatever reason it has become more commonly known as "Mexico"), it is commonly understood to mean the USA (even our government uses this shorthand globally, e.g. at the customs office you will see "United States Customs"), and it won't conflict with any other persons' use of "America". Additionally, within the USA, "United States" is commonly used and understood and won't raise any eyebrows or cause any confusion; it's a good global safe bet.

If you're *really* concerned, "USA" is 100% safe in and out of the country.

And, of course, within the USA, you can always say "America" without issue.

As Marcel Turing noted in the question comments, it isn't really an issue of "correctness" as much as it is an issue of common usage. Of course, in reality, it's slightly more complex, because while in an ideal world people wouldn't take offense at things other people innocently say, that isn't how it works. So you always need to at least be aware of local attitudes (and again, when in doubt, just go with "USA").

Personally, when I'm home I say "America", and when I'm travelling (even to e.g. Canada) I say "United States". This has never caused an issue (even in Mexico).

---

Edit: As for the demonym, as ntoskrnl points out in the question comments, "American" is the official one (but is shared with the continental demonym) and is usually understood, depending on the context, as referring to the country (with the same caveats as above; and unless the context is continents) with the only other real global option being "US Citizen". Wikipedia has a good article on [Names for US Citizens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_for_United_States_citizens). It also gives a nice overview of "American" in [Demonyms: Cultural Problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym#Cultural_problems).

The adjectival form has essentially the same issues, but without the "US Citizen" option.

[ChrisW's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/155820/55308) gives a nice overview of context.

---

Please note this is all based mostly on personal experience, not so much canonical reference.

Comment: It's also worth noting that on the internet, "local attitudes" doesn't really mean as much. So if you are referring to the country in something that you are publicly posting online, "United States" and, even more so, "USA", would be clear and globally understood.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the ppl of Canada talk of their country as America and of themselves as Americans. I mean, it would be equally valid.

Comment: Does *natural* mean 'native' or 'naturalised'?

Comment: @TimLymington Native; clarified. Sorry, it's confusing enough in our Constitution, I don't know why I always think it will be less confusing anywhere else. I have my own personal issues around "native" as far as the USA goes.

Answer (score 7):

> When speaking to a person from Canada, he argued that it was incorrect to call the country America. Instead, I should be saying the United States (of America).

IMO when a 'normal' Canadian says "American" in conversation they mean "from or of the USA", and explicitly mean "not Canadian".

As a Canadian I often don't use the word "America" to refer to the country: I'd say, "the U.S." as in "in the U.S. they do things differently", or "the States" as in "he emigrated to  the States".

If someone in Europe talks about "America", I'd assume:

- If they're talking about the 17th century then they mean the continent
- If they're talking about politics then they mean the U.S.A.
- If they're talk about lifestyle ("in America they have big cars, eat at McDonald's, go to High School") then they probably mean the U.S.A but what they say may be applicable to Canada too.

So for me (speaking as a Canadian) the word "America" mostly means "the U.S.A.": and I think most other English-speaking people agree.

If I want a word that includes Canadians or Canada and not just Americans/the U.S.A., I'd say 'North America', for example "NORAD was created to defend North America".

Perhaps your friend is technically/pedantically correct, but IMO their usage is unconventional.

Comment: +1 for Egg McMuffins; although I don't have a car.

Answer (score 6):

While it is true that Spanish speakers refer to these ideas differently, this site's purview is "English Language and Usage". In the US and UK (and, I believe, Australia), if you say, "I've been living in America for 6 months", that indicates living in the US. Perhaps it's a misnomer, but that's the way the term has evolved. English, like most languages, is full of quirks like that. I have met Canadians who object to that use of the word America in principle, but I've never heard of a Canadian who would describe him/herself as an American; that's just not the meaning in English. They have a perfectly good demonym in the word "Canadian", and there isn't another demonym for Americans besides "American".

Also, how continents are viewed is different in different cultures. Some consider Europe and Asia to be one continent, and some consider Europe, Asia and Africa to be a single continent (as they are one contiguous land mass). To Americans and Canadians, North America is one continent, and South America is a neighboring continent. (This is also more accurate scientifically, as the two come from different parts of earlier land masses -- South America is more closely related to Africa, geologically speaking, than it is to North America.) So you would very rarely describe someone from Brazil or Argentina as an American in English. "South American" or "Latin American", yes, but just "American", no.

Answer (score 5):

As a German, I can say that we also use "Amerika" to refer to the United States. While this is recognized by nearly all Europeans as being incorrect, they still use it for simplicity. Another term used especially in writing is "United States" (without America). If correctness is of the essence, we of course use "USA".

A term like "The Americas" by the way does not exist in German (also not in French if I'm not mistaken). There is really no other word for the combined North and South America than "Amerika".

Answer (score 4):

Your Canadian friend is both correct and incorrect.  He is a North American, not an *American* as it's understood by the majority of the world.  The name of our shared continent is **North America**, not **America**.

The name for the combined landmasses of North and South America is the **Americas**.  And, while you could in theory use the term *American* to describe anyone from those landmasses, most of the residents of the individual countries would take umbrage to that.

Most of the people across the world tend to identify primarily by their cultural groups.  For some this represents national identities, some racial or ethnic identities, and for some this could be the continent, and in some cases all of the above.  (*e.g.* Han Chinese vs Asian)

The usage of America and American for the USA dates back to the colonial period, prior to our revolutionary war.  [See here for more information.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Revolution)

The original name for the region was [British America](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_America).  This did, of course, include Canada.  And, a resident of the region prior to the revolution would have declared themselves to be British.

It was not until after our revolutionary war, and the signing of the Articles of Confederation that the *United States of America* was founded.  And, this was the point where the loyalties were divided and a new identity was forged.  The Americans of the United States viewed themselves as a distinct new nationality.  The Canadians remained loyal to the British Crown, and considered themselves British.

Looking at the construction of the name of our country, you will see America right in the name.  The United States is actually a description of the structure of our country.  We are the only country on the continent with America in its name.

America consists of 50 individual states, each of which functions with some degree of autonomy, under a greater federal framework.

So, in shortening our name to the United States, we are actually being ambiguous.  In theory there could be other united states in the world.  But, the United States of *America* makes it clear which country we are speaking of.

So, by convention, and by virtue of our right to call ourselves whatever we choose, we are **Americans**.

Answer (score 3):

Referring to the United States (of America) as "America" might be an example of [synedoche](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche) also.

> A **synecdoche** is a figure of speech in which a term for a part of something refers to the whole of something, or vice-versa.

---

> **The [Americas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americas)**, or **America** also known as the New World, are the combined continental landmasses of North America and South America, in the Western Hemisphere.

Though it is debated whether it is a synedoche or not in some of the sources and some say that it is simply an abbreviation.

---

Also for the second part of the question:

Yes, America is understood as the United States of America globally also. It is simply another name and it is more convenient to use.

Comment: The second part was exactly his argument. Wikipedia appears to contradict itself or has given America two different definitions. One refers the the USA while the other refers to the combined landmasses of NA and SA.

Comment: @krikara: If it is a synedoche or abbreviation, it wouldn't be a contradiction. The name of the country is long, so it is a natural process to shorten the name. And there are historical connotations also as mentioned.

Comment: @krikara “America” ≠ “The Americas”

Answer (score 3):

The people of a country are usually referred to by the *geographic* location in their country's name. We don't talk about Republicans from the Republic of France, we talk about the French. We don't talk about Unitedians or Kingdomians, we talk about the British or English*. We didn't talk about Unionists or Socialists or Republicans from the former/future USSR, we talked about Soviets (even though technically it's a government form, not a geography, it's the least generic term). So, people of the USA are Americans, not Unitedians or Statesians. There's no other *X Y of America*, so no ambiguity.

- British being citizens of the U.K., or inhabitants of the British Isles/Britain (excluding the Irish Republic). English for citizens of England specifically, although most Americans use it to cover anyone in the U.K.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not particularly well travelled or an expert, but, as a self-described American, IMHO American is a perfectly valid word for describing an inhabitant of the USA. The Google search for "American define" supports me in saying this (link [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=american&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb#channel=fflb&q=american+define&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial)). For referring to an inhabitant of the continent of North America, I would use North American. For referring to someone in North America or South America, I would use "an inhabitant of the Americas" or something similar.

Comment: It's worth noting that Google and many internet users are (United States of) American, though.

Comment: @augurar - well that is true for google.com.  Google has a site for most countries.  If you do a search outside of the the US site you will find different things.

Answer (score -1):

A person living in Canada is from [America](http://www.boston.com/bostonglobe/ideas/articles/2010/07/04/where_america_really_came_from/).  The first map by Waldseemüller shows both continents referred to as America.  I work with people in South America that simply say they are from America.  It is very narrow-minded for the US to think they own the word because it is part of their country's name... and actually United States of America would signify they are on the continent of America.  So yes our fellow Canadians live in America.

Just a [great/funny site](http://www.usaisnotamerica.com/index.php) that I couldn't believe was out there.

Comment: Is this only a Canadian view that America is not a country?

Comment: Yet, you felt the need to explain that these people were from *South* America.  Virginia and West Virginia were once one state.  Would you lump them together?  How about *The Carolinas*?  Current usage trumps antiquity.

Comment: @DavidM - I am saying they can say they are both from South America or America.  South America would be more accurate.  Brazil would be even more accurate.  We can keep going down to the street level.  Missing your point.

Comment: @RyeBread My point is that most people don't introduce ambiguity into where they are from.  Living in New England, I know literally thousands of Brazilians, and they never call themselves anything but Brazilian.

Comment: @DavidM - they refer to themselves as in America all the time.  I am guessing that it is because we are on global calls and the importance of the exact country isn't a huge factor but helps people understand their region/timezone.  Also when I am over in France the entire two continents are often referred to as America.  I know people from the US refer to themselves as Americans and from America.  What I am saying is that other countries are not wrong in saying they are from America.  Is there ambiguity, maybe.  Probably for the same reason you haven't announced your address.

Comment: I can accept that point, but I would argue that these are *not* native English speakers.  The idea that they would truncate a plural is not even remotely unbelievable.  But, as to the continent being called America, I don't think you can support that.  The continents are North and South America respectively.  And, when combined, they are called *The Americas*.  Someone from the Americas is legitimately an American, but no one would say they were American.  (i.e. They would always use the word *an*.)

Comment: In Spanish, "The Americas" is just called "América": A continent with three regions: North America, Central America and South America. It makes sense and it is consistent with, say, Western Europe or South Asia.

Comment: @oopscene - Exactly.  We (people in the US) don't own the word because we are the largest English speaking country... America isn't even an English word.

Comment: @oopscene How do you translate USA into Spanish?

Comment: @RyeBread When you say "narrow-minded" you imply an oversight or motive of some sort. In reality, we call ourselves "American" here simply because over time, for whatever reason, that's become the common shorthand for it in the context of communication with other citizens of our country. You couldn't really say that somebody here is "narrow-minded" based only on their usage of "America", it's just not the language norm to fully expand the country name, and there's not much more to it than that. Personally, when I travel, I say "United States" (still shorthand) to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @JasonC - this is a little bit different.  There are probably only a few other instances were the continental name drifts into a country name.  For example would you think that someone from Africa was from South Africa?

Comment: @RyeBread It doesn't really matter how many other [dis]similar instances there are, it's simply AE linguistic shorthand at this point. The point is it's a usage in American English that isn't common in Canadian English, and that's pretty much it. There's not really any "narrow-mindedness" behind it at this point, it's simply a difference in dialects, albeit an unfortunate one (unfortunate because innocent AE usage can easily and inadvertently overlap with potentially offensive/charged CE usage). The potential for misunderstanding there is why I'd recommend "United States" outside of the USA.

Comment: @JasonC - I am not saying it isn't short-hand for a person from the US to say they are from America.  I am also not saying that it isn't a common thought amongst people from the US.  I am simply stating that the word America can be used by anyone on the 2 continents and they would be correct in stating this.

Comment: @RyeBread You aren't "simply" saying that. You are implying more. If you were "simply" saying that, you would be able to "simply" say that without including the *"It is very narrow-minded for the US to think they own the word because it is part of their country's name"* that I was clearly and specifically responding to. I disagree with that, but that's a totally reasonable thing to think and a totally valid statement to make -- so, at least acknowledge that it was part of your point instead of trying to disguise it as "simply" trying to say something.

Comment: @Krikara: Estados Unidos de América (meaning that, inside América [read it as a continent with three regions, as I mentioned before], there is a set of states that are united as a country)

Comment: @oopscene By saying América in Spanish, people would think that I am referring to "the Americas" as opposed to USA?

Comment: @Krikara: Exactly! Actually in my city there is an avenue named América; and once when a friend of USA was here told me: "Oh, a street honouring my country!"; and I told him: "Actually, honouring the continent!" and this same discussion started right there.

Comment: @oopscene That is also exactly what the English name means, just, for some reason, it was not named as "The United States of the Americas". If that were the name, it would probably not get called "America" today!

Comment: @RyeBread, be careful -- many "Americans" (USAians) consider Canada to be Disneyland North, sort of part of the USA!